# SELECT WHERE IN (a,b,c) query : sort the results by order of condition (a,b,c)

Tags: mysql, sorting

in the `image_tags` table i have lots of `aaa` tags and only one `bbb` tag

i want to get the rows with this tags but in order of `IN ('bbb', 'aaa')` , basically 
i want the `bbb` tags to be on top and after that `aaa` tags and then order them by id desc

i got this but it doesn't work and still i get `aaa` tag on top

```
SELECT image_tags.tag
FROM `image_tags`
WHERE image_tags.tag
IN (
'bbb', 'aaa'
)
ORDER BY FIELD( 'bbb', 'aaa' ) , id DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: use order by image_tags.tag desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(image_tags.tag, 'bbb', 'aaa' ) , id DESC
```

You are missing the first argument to `field()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, basically you want to arrange the name in descending order then id desc.

```
SELECT image_tags.tag
    FROM `image_tags`
    WHERE image_tags.tag
    IN (
    'bbb', 'aaa'
    )
    ORDER BY image_tags.tag Desc , id DESC
    LIMIT 20
```

**EDIT**

I have got the question wrong, one way to solve the problem has already been stated by @Gordon Linoff which will work in mysql, another solution

```
SELECT image_tags.tag
    FROM `image_tags`
    WHERE image_tags.tag
    IN (
    'bbb', 'aaa'
    )
    ORDER BY case when 'bbb' then 1 when 'aaa' then 2 end , id DESC
```

This will work in sql too.

Comment: this would order them by characters of tags not order of them in condition

Comment: You also wanted to get 'bbb' on top, and i guess the above query will do the same.

Comment: have you executed the query?

Comment: the tags are dynamic , `bbb` is just a example .... i want the first tag in the condition to be in top and it could be anything